# Is there a quick way to install packages if there is a prompt?

Tags: bash, software-installation, apt, command-not-found

If I want to install a package,

```
wlhunag: ~ $ pip install django
The program 'pip' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install python-pip
wlhunag: ~ $
```

I wonder if there is a quick way to install the required packages without manually typing the line

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
```

Comment: I use my mouse: triple click to select the `sudo ...` line, and middle click to paste. Assumes you're not at a system console.

Comment: For that specific instance, you can pipe to `tail -1` easily like: `!! | tail -1 | bash`. This is potentially dangerous, it will run the last line of output (I'm assuming that the `apt-get` command is on its own line?).

Comment: It seems `!! | tail -1 | bash` doesn't work on this situation.

Comment: What does `pip install django | tail -1` return?

Comment: Wow, that's impressively lazy. Sorry, I just had to say it...

Comment: @nanny , `pip install django | tail -1` returns the same message.

Comment: @FaheemMitha , No problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cut and paste is the quickest to install the package. If you are in gnome terminal you can triple click the `sudo apt-get ...` line and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> (copy) and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> (paste) followed by <kbd>Return</kbd>

However in your case I recommend you do:

```
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
sudo python get-pip.py
```

so you have the [latest version](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing.html#install-pip), which is probably not in the repository you would get when you install it with `apt-get`.

If you have Python 2.7.9  or any of the 3.4 series, `pip` is included in the [distribution](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing.html#pip-included-with-python) and you don't need to install it.

Answer (score 4):

That comes from command-not-found, which is run from shell script... so you could just modify the shell function to give a "would you like to install it" prompt, or alternatively leave it in a variable (so you'd then just type `$doINST` or something). Or use `history -s` to append them to the history, then you'd just press up.

Answer (score 1):

Check out `aptsh`. Just came across it by accident. Sample session (hitting tab in the shell does intelligent tab completion):

```
root@orwell:/home/faheem# aptsh
Generating and mapping caches...
Reading commands history...
aptsh> 
add              depends          dump-cfg         madison          queue*           show             unmet            
autoclean        dist-upgrade     dumpavail        news             quit             showpkg          update           
build-dep        dotty            help*            orphans*         rdepends         showsrc          upgrade          
changelog        dpkg*            install          pkgnames         remove           source           whatis           
check            dselect-upgrade  listfiles        policy           rls              stats            whichpkg         
clean            dump             ls               purge            search           toupgrade        
aptsh> install octave
Display all 113 possibilities? (y or n)
octave                        octave-fpl                    octave-miscellaneous          octave-plot                   octave-zenity
octave-ad                     octave-ftp                    octave-missing-functions      octave-plplot                 octave2.0-emacsen
octave-ann                    octave-ga                     octave-mpi                    octave-psychtoolbox-3         octave2.0-htmldoc
octave-audio                  octave-gdf                    octave-msh                    octave-quaternion             octave2.0-info
octave-benchmark              octave-general                octave-multicore              octave-secs1d                 octave3.0
octave-bim                    octave-geometry               octave-nan                    octave-secs2d                 octave3.0-info
octave-bioinfo                octave-gmt                    octave-nlopt                  octave-signal                 octave3.1
octave-biosig                 octave-gsl                    octave-nlwing2                octave-simp                   octave3.1-doc
octave-combinatorics          octave-headers                octave-nnet                   octave-sockets                octave3.1-emacsen
octave-common                 octave-htmldoc                octave-nurbs                  octave-sp                     octave3.1-headers
octave-communications         octave-ident                  octave-ocs                    octave-specfun                octave3.1-htmldoc
octave-communications-common  octave-image                  octave-octcdf                 octave-splines                octave3.1-info
octave-control                octave-info                   octave-octgpr                 octave-statistics             octave3.2
octave-data-smoothing         octave-informationtheory      octave-odepkg                 octave-strings                octave3.2-common
octave-dataframe              octave-integration            octave-openmpi-ext            octave-struct                 octave3.2-dbg
octave-dbg                    octave-io                     octave-optim                  octave-sundials               octave3.2-doc
octave-dicom                  octave-irsa                   octave-optiminterp            octave-symband                octave3.2-emacsen
octave-doc                    octave-java                   octave-outliers               octave-symbolic               octave3.2-headers
octave-econometrics           octave-lhapdf                 octave-parallel               octave-time                   octave3.2-htmldoc
octave-emacsen                octave-linear-algebra         octave-pdb                    octave-tsa                    octave3.2-info
octave-epstk                  octave-ltfat                  octave-pfstools               octave-vlfeat                 octavede
octave-financial              octave-ltfat-common           octave-physicalconstants      octave-vrml                   
octave-fixed                  octave-mapping                octave-pkg-dev                octave-xraylib                
aptsh> install octave-
octave-ad                     octave-epstk                  octave-irsa                   octave-octgpr                 octave-sockets
octave-ann                    octave-financial              octave-java                   octave-odepkg                 octave-sp
octave-audio                  octave-fixed                  octave-lhapdf                 octave-openmpi-ext            octave-specfun
octave-benchmark              octave-fpl                    octave-linear-algebra         octave-optim                  octave-splines
octave-bim                    octave-ftp                    octave-ltfat                  octave-optiminterp            octave-statistics
octave-bioinfo                octave-ga                     octave-ltfat-common           octave-outliers               octave-strings
octave-biosig                 octave-gdf                    octave-mapping                octave-parallel               octave-struct
octave-combinatorics          octave-general                octave-miscellaneous          octave-pdb                    octave-sundials
octave-common                 octave-geometry               octave-missing-functions      octave-pfstools               octave-symband
octave-communications         octave-gmt                    octave-mpi                    octave-physicalconstants      octave-symbolic
octave-communications-common  octave-gsl                    octave-msh                    octave-pkg-dev                octave-time
octave-control                octave-headers                octave-multicore              octave-plot                   octave-tsa
octave-data-smoothing         octave-htmldoc                octave-nan                    octave-plplot                 octave-vlfeat
octave-dataframe              octave-ident                  octave-nlopt                  octave-psychtoolbox-3         octave-vrml
octave-dbg                    octave-image                  octave-nlwing2                octave-quaternion             octave-xraylib
octave-dicom                  octave-info                   octave-nnet                   octave-secs1d                 octave-zenity
octave-doc                    octave-informationtheory      octave-nurbs                  octave-secs2d                 
octave-econometrics           octave-integration            octave-ocs                    octave-signal                 
octave-emacsen                octave-io                     octave-octcdf                 octave-simp                   
aptsh> install octave-io 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  gnuplot-x11 libatlas3-base libcamd2.2.0 libccolamd2.7.1 libcholmod1.7.1 libcxsparse2.2.3 libgl2ps0 libglpk0 libjexcelapi-java liboctave1 libqhull5
  libqrupdate1 octave octave-common octave-java
Suggested packages:
  gnuplot-doc libiodbc2-dev libmysqlclient-dev octave-info octave-doc octave-htmldoc
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  gnuplot-nox
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  gnuplot-x11 libatlas3-base libcamd2.2.0 libccolamd2.7.1 libcholmod1.7.1 libcxsparse2.2.3 libgl2ps0 libglpk0 libjexcelapi-java liboctave1 libqhull5
  libqrupdate1 octave octave-common octave-io octave-java
0 upgraded, 16 newly installed, 1 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
Need to get 9,850 kB/22.1 MB of archives.
After this operation, 64.6 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]?
```

Answer (score 1):

if you're using bash, you could add this:

```
alias api='sudo apt-get install'
```

or

```
alias api='sudo aptitude install'
```

You would only have to type api "package name". Alternatively if you're looking for python only, you could install anaconda found here: https://store.continuum.io/cshop/anaconda/

and then you can use conda update which would update all of the packages found in anaconda.